# how can I run pick_an_place on non-pr2 robot?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a robot which has two dynamixel based arm. I am using a kinect in the head for sensor perception. I can manipulate my arms by /follow_joint_trajectory and also from arm_navigation.launch file which has been created by planning_description_configuration wizard. I can also manipulate the arm using warehouse_viewer. I have checked the pick_and_place_demos by PR2 in gazebo. But I find this really complex. Can anybody guide me step-by-step that how can I do same type of work on my non-PR2 robot???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58330/how-can-i-run-pick_an_place-on-non-pr2-robot?/) by [jontromanab](https://answers.ros.org/users/2662/jontromanab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2013-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Indeed pick & place (object_manipulation stack) is complex.
You already managed to get your arm working in the warehouse_viewer which means you have kinematics and robot_description running.

What is complex is the whole setup (everything must be connected together). You may want to have a look at a diagram we created to understand the different parts of object_manipulation_stack Page 6 of [this tutorial](http://mrl.isr.uc.pt/events/iros2012tutorial/download/Presentations/IROS2012-Hands-on-6.pdf) :

We also went for a rewrite of the wrapper (the thing commanding sub-functions to do pick and place) in our project. You can find an early version of our wrapper in the shadow sr-manipulation stack [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eshadowrobot/sr-manipulation/trunk/files/head:/sr_pick_and_place/lib/sr_pick_and_place) as well as launch files that startup a lot of things.
It is not in a release state but you may find some ideas on how to proceed.
Hope this helped.

---

Originally posted by [GuiHome](https://answers.ros.org/users/768/guihome/) with karma: 242 on 2013-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1